# r date/time stamp not printing same value as Values chart is showing

Tags: r, datetime, utc, gmt

I have a date/time stamp that is in GMT/UTC in the source data.  I am trying to get it's local date/time (corrected for DST if applicable) based on the Airport Code.  The problem I am running into is that when I go to print out both times into a new `data.table`, the GMT column will not stay in GMT, nor will the Local column stay in Airport Local time.  They keep reverting to system local.  I can see that the code is working by viewing the Values in the Environment frame. I have tried the force_tz function, the posixct function, and quite a few others I have found online, but I keep getting the same results.

Here is my code.

```
library(readxl)
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(fastmatch)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
library(RcppBDT)
library(lubridate)
library(openxlsx)
##library(anytime)

## Load time zone data sheet
TZData  <- read_excel("TZDataFile.xlsx")
TZData <- as.data.table(TZData)
TZRange <- TZData[,1]
TZRange <- as.data.frame(TZRange)

##Bring in test data
TD  <- read_excel("Test dates.xlsx", col_types = c("text", "text"))
TD <- as.data.table(TD)

####Start Time Conversion Code####

## Define variables
Station <- TD[,1] ##Station
GMT <- TD[,2] ##Date/time stamp in GMT to be converted to local
z <- nrow(TD)+0
APLDateTime <- data.frame(GMT = as.POSIXct(as.Date(character()), tz = "UTC"), 
                          Local = as.POSIXct(as.Date(character())))
for (i in 1:z) {
  STA <- as.character(Station[i,1]) ## Get Station
  APCode <- as.integer(fmatch(STA, TZRange[,1])) ## Match station on Time Zone Data sheet
  TZO <- as.integer(TZData[APCode,4]) ## get Station specific Time Zone Offset
  TZDC <- as.character(TZData[APCode,3])
  GMTDteTmeStamp <- as.double(TD[i,2]) ## get GMT time to be converted
  GMTDteTmeValue <- as.POSIXct((GMTDteTmeStamp) * 86400
                               , origin = as.POSIXct("1899-12-30", tz = "UTC")
                               , tz = "UTC")
  APLDteTmeValue2 <- as.POSIXct((GMTDteTmeStamp) * 86400, origin = "1899-12-30", tz = TZDC)
    test = force_tz(GMTDteTmeValue, "UTC")
    APLDateTime[i,1] <- test
    APLDateTime[i,2] <- APLDteTmeValue2
  }
```

My sample data is:

```
   Sta          GMT Dept
 1: LHR 43138.51666666667
 2: PHL 43139.51666666667
 3: DFW 43168.51666666667
 4: DFW 43169.51666666667
 5: DFW 43170.51666666667
 6: DFW 43171.51666666667
 7: DFW 43172.51666666667
 8: PHX 43141.51666666667
 9: LAX 43142.51666666667
10: BCN 43143.51666666667
11: SCL 43144.51666666667
12: GIG 43176.51666666667
13: GIG 43177.51666666667
14: GIG 43178.51666666667
```

My code has the Time Zone codes relative to the Airport codes.

```
Therefore the TZDC would be:
LHR = "Europe/London"
DFW = "America/Chicago"
GIG = "America/Sao_Paulo"
```

The GMT time should read 12:24 for all rows.

Thanks for the help